# How to Transfer Images from Server to Client as fast as possible?

Tags: java, networking, image-processing, arrays

Transferring Images from Server to Client on other network is difficult especially if any one of them is connected on a net connection of low bandwidth.
Both of them are behind NAT but by using TCP punching they are able to connect.

I have converted Images to bytes and then transferred it but it takes to long for a single image to pop up.

So I tried dividing the bytes in multiple frames and then sending it but still the image takes time to load and becomes distorted (One of the reason for distortion is noise but it doesn't affect the image that much).

Here is my code for both of them:-

**Server Code(The one who sends the Image)**

```
public class ImageSend extends Thread{

    public Socket s;
    DataOutputStream dout;
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    ImageSend(Socket clientSocket, DataOutputStream dout1) throws Exception {
        s = clientSocket;
        dout = dout1;
        start();
    }

    public void run(){

        System.out.println("System at Image Sender");
        JFrame f = new JFrame("MY PC");
        f.setLocation(80, 100);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(1200, 600);
        while(true){
        try{    
        Rectangle size = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(size);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        baos.flush();
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpeg", baos);
        img.flush();

        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
        int length = bytes.length;
        System.out.println("Image size is:"+length/1024+"kb");
        dout.writeInt(bytes.length);



         int x = 0;
         int y = length /4;
         int temp = y;
         byte[] c = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, x, y);
         sleep(10);


         byte[] d = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, y+1, y +temp);
         sleep(10);

         byte[] e = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, y+temp+1, y+temp+temp);
         sleep(10);

         byte[] g = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, y+temp+temp+1, length);
         sleep(10);

         byte[] data1 = ArrayUtils.addAll(c, d);
         byte[] data2 = ArrayUtils.addAll(e, g);
         byte[] data = ArrayUtils.addAll(data1, data2);

         InputStream ian = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
         BufferedImage bimg =ImageIO.read(ian);
         Image image = bimg.getScaledInstance(f.getContentPane().getWidth(), f.getContentPane().getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
         Graphics graphocs = f.getContentPane().getGraphics();
         graphocs.drawImage(image,0,0,f.getContentPane().getWidth(),f.getContentPane().getHeight(),f);

         dout.writeInt(c.length);
         dout.write(c, 0, c.length);

         dout.writeInt(d.length);
         dout.write(d, 0, d.length);

         dout.writeInt(e.length);
         dout.write(e, 0, e.length);

         dout.writeInt(g.length);
         dout.write(g, 0, g.length);

         System.out.println("Image sent to the Client");
        baos.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    }
}
```

**Client Code(Who Receives the Image)**

```
public class ImageReceive extends Thread{

    public Socket s;
    DataInputStream din;
    JFrame f;

    ImageReceive(Socket clientSocket, DataInputStream din1, JFrame frame) throws Exception {
        s = clientSocket;
        din = din1;
        f = frame;
        start();
    }

    public void run(){

        System.out.println("\nSystem at Image Receiver");

     while(true){   
            try {
                int len = din.readInt();
                System.out.println("Image Size: " + len/1024 + "KB");

                int len1 = din.readInt();
                byte[] a1 = new byte[len1];
                System.out.println(len1/1024 +"kb");
                din.readFully(a1);
                sleep(10);
                int len2 = din.readInt();
                System.out.println(len2/1024 +"kb");
                byte[] a2 = new byte[len2];
                din.readFully(a2);
                sleep(10);
                int len3 = din.readInt();
                System.out.println(len3/1024 +"kb");
                byte[] a3 = new byte[len3];
                din.readFully(a3);
                sleep(10);
                int len4 = din.readInt();
                System.out.println(len4/1024 +"kb");
                byte[] a4 = new byte[len4];
                din.readFully(a4);
                sleep(10);
                byte[] Comdata1 = ArrayUtils.addAll(a1, a2);
                byte[] Comdata2 = ArrayUtils.addAll(a3, a4);
                byte[] Comdata = ArrayUtils.addAll(Comdata1, Comdata2);
                sleep(100);
                InputStream ian = new ByteArrayInputStream(Comdata);
                BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(ian);

                sleep(100);
                Image img = bImage.getScaledInstance(f.getContentPane().getWidth(), f.getContentPane().getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

                Graphics graphics = f.getContentPane().getGraphics();
                graphics.drawImage(img, 0, 0, f.getContentPane().getWidth(), f.getContentPane().getHeight(), f);
} catch (IOException|InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ImageReceive.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }


    }

    }
}
```

Please Suggest something so that I can transfer the images at faster rate and I would be thankful if you could show me some code for it.

Thank you for your Help!!

Comment: Why aren't you just sending the jpeg file? AFAIK a  BufferedImage stores every pixel, so it's like sending a not compressed image (bitmap)

Comment: Pablo , Could you give some code and explain?